# jquery Selector problem

Tags: jquery, selector

How to select all the child elements within a certain `<div>` except the active one? For example:

```
<div>
    <a id="1" class="item" href="#">Item 1 </a>
    <a id="2" class="item" href="#">Item 2 </a>
    <a id="3" class="item" href="#">Item 3 </a>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".item").mouseover(function() {


        // HOW TO hide all the items with class item except this one


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude `this` (the current element), like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").mouseover(function() {
       $(".item").not(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Or, if they're always siblings use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").mouseover(function() {
       $(".item").siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good lord, I beat @Nick Craver (with almost the same answer) by a whole *17 seconds* O_O Although, admittedly, my variation didn't work, so that does take some of the joy out of it... =/

Comment: @David - Your answer would throw some very odd errors, `this` isn't a string, it's a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks. I am so confused about these selectors

Comment: @mrNepal - I suggest starting out here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').not($(this).show()).hide();
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap `this` or `.show()` it...if it weren't *already* visible, we couldn't have moused over it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it differently... Hide all, then show me:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").mouseover(function() {

        // Hide all:
        $('.item').hide();

        // Show "me":
        $(this).show();


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(this)` selector to except the item on mouse over.